# дата парситься кусками в экселе

Tags: база-данных, парсер, excel, синтаксис, dataset

[image: Данные в формате день месяц год почему-то разделяются кусками]

[image: не знаю как это исправить]

[image: почему-то просит изменить конечные ячейки]

Во время разделения данных вроде бы отображает все правильно, но по итогу какие-то куски таблицы не разделяются

Comment: Все там делится. Например, 1/3/1900 - это 3 (тройка) в формате даты.Установить в столбцах B:D формат ячеек общий

Comment: Спасибо большое!